# dojo.io.iframe.send file download working indicator

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I am using dojo.io.iframe.send to implement a file download from server. This works fine but the file is actually generated and can take some time. I have added a dialog with a working indicator (gif) but I can't seem to get it to close. The code is:

```
  var t = this;
  new t.LoadingView(t).render();

  dojo.io.iframe.send({
    url : "/downloadzip",
    handleAs: "json",
  }).then(function(data){

    console.info("HERE");

    if(data.error != null) {

      console.info("HERE2");

      // Remove the loading dialog
      destroyDialog("id_dialog");
    }
    else
    {
      console.info("HERE3");
      // Remove the loading dialog
      destroyDialog("id_dialog");
    }
  }, function(err) {
    console.info("HERE4");
    if(err.error != null && err.error !== undefined) {

      // Remove the loading dialog
      destroyDialog("id_dialog");
    } else {

      // Remove the loading dialog
      destroyDialog("id_dialog");
    }
  });
```

and the file is downloaded and saved by the browser but the ".then" function is never reached. (ie I never see the console log points).

Is there a way to get this working or a better way to make this work with dojo?

Thanks.

Comment: What is you browser support constraint ? If you don;t care about IE9 and lower, you can use Blob. You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to support IE9 but possibly I could use this for supported browsers and ignore for non supported. Unless there is a better browser independent method. Thanks Ben.